# data validation exclude blank from list

Tags: microsoft-excel

My question is: How can I make a drop-down list that takes dynamic data (dates) and have "blank" cells, <""> because there function that prints date or "" .

I've tried this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PcF04bTSOM, but didn't work for me because it works only for alphabetical and doesn't work for numeric.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury of adding another column to your worksheet, you can compress the list of dates in a new column. Then, use the new column as your validation list rather than the original dates from your formula.

**Example:**
Column `A` includes random dates and blanks generated by the formula below (you won't use this formula).

```
=IF(RAND()>0.2,RANDBETWEEN(1,12)&"/"&RANDBETWEEN(1,28)&"/2013","")
```

In Column `B`, I have a compressed list of these random dates. This list is generated using the array formula below.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$30<>"",DATEVALUE($A$2:$A$30)),ROW()-1),"")
```

You must enter the formula by clicking in the formula bar and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, fill down. This will generate an ordered list of the dates from `A`, skipping any blanks. You will want to apply a Date format to this list.

Finally, set up the validation rule for your dropdown by using List validation. Use the following for your Source.

```
=INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNT(B:B)+1)
```

If your Source list is on a different sheet than your dropdown, you will need to use a dynamic named range instead of the hard-coded reference to column `B`. You can find instructions for how to do this [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal15.html).

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get same result as you, it's blank list in drop down menu.
I'm currently using the first option as explained in youtube+converted from numbers to text, and it half works for me, because I need it in number (DATE)(DD/MM/YYYY DDD) format.
I can show it "like" I need, but can't do any calculation with this (DD/MM/YYYY DDD) text.